# Как вообще правильно удалять строки из DataTable?

Tags: c#

Есть dataTable. Перебираю строки с помощью *foreach*. При определенном условии удаляю строку:

```
foreach( DataRow dr in dt)
{
   If (dr["Name"} = "Bob")
   {
        dr.Delete();
        dt.AcceptChanges();
   }
 }
```

При последующем обходе цикла появляется исключение "*Коллекция изменена,возможно операция перечисления не будет выполнена*". Операция перечисления на самом деле не корректно будет отрабатывать? И как вообще правильно удалять строки из DataTable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5648389/7198805

Comment: Понял ошибку, спасибо. dt.AcceptChanges(); нужно вынести за цикл